# ActionView::Template::Error (dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting the following error when I try to start a Rails application (using code from Ryan Bates' railscasts.com). According to a Google search, someone else had a similar error after they uninstalled Macports, which I also recently did. However, his error was related to the pg gem, which my code is not using.  There's several other similar posts on SO, but they're related to Does anyone know what might be wrong

```
h: line 1:  1511 Trace/BPT trap          node /var/folders/rc/rcFucU9oF5qT5vZE\+tL1JE\+\+\+TI/-Tmp-/execjs20121008-1505-1v364bs.js 2>&1


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-08 23:45:06 -0700
Processing by TopicsController#index as HTML
  Topic Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "topics".* FROM "topics" ORDER BY sticky desc
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."topic_id" = 4
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."topic_id" = 1
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."topic_id" = 2
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."topic_id" = 3
  Rendered topics/index.html.erb within layouts/application (216.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1479ms

ActionView::Template::Error (dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node
  Reason: image not found

  (in /Users/mm/Sites/authorizationPart1/forum-after/app/assets/javascripts/sessions.js.coffee)):
    3:   <head>
    4:     <title>Forum</title>
    5:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
    6:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    7:     <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
    8:   </head>
    9:   <body>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___3636075050981736840_2167808160'


^C[2012-10-08 23:48:50] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2012-10-08 23:48:50] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
Exiting
```

Gem list

```
aaronh-chronic (0.3.9 ruby)
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.2.8 ruby, 3.2.6, 3.1.3, 3.0.4)
actionpack (3.2.8 ruby, 3.2.6, 3.1.3, 3.0.4)
activemodel (3.2.8 ruby, 3.2.6, 3.1.3, 3.0.4)
activerecord (3.2.8 ruby, 3.2.6, 3.1.3, 3.0.4)
activeresource (3.2.8 ruby, 3.2.6, 3.1.3, 3.0.4)
activesupport (3.2.8 ruby, 3.2.6, 3.1.3, 3.0.4)
acts-as-taggable-on (2.3.3)
acts_as_indexed (0.7.8)
addressable (2.3.2, 2.2.8, 2.2.6 ruby, 2.0.2)
ansi (1.4.3, 1.4.2)
arel (3.0.2 ruby, 2.2.3, 2.0.10, 2.0.8)
awesome_nested_set (2.1.5, 2.1.3)
awesome_print (1.1.0)
babosa (0.3.8, 0.3.7)
backbone-on-rails (0.9.2.1, 0.9.2.0)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1 ruby)
binding_of_caller (0.6.8)
bson (1.7.0)
bson_ext (1.7.0)
builder (3.1.3, 3.0.3 ruby, 3.0.2, 3.0.0 ruby, 2.1.2)
bundler (1.2.1, 1.2.0.pre.1)
capybara (1.1.2 ruby)
cargo_wiki (1.0.1)
carrierwave (0.5.8)
childprocess (0.3.5, 0.3.0 ruby)
chunky_png (1.2.6)
coderay (1.0.7, 1.0.5 ruby, 0.9.7)
coffee-rails (3.2.2 ruby, 3.1.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0 ruby)
coffee-script-source (1.3.3 ruby, 1.3.1)
columnize (0.3.6)
commonjs (0.2.6)
compass (0.12.2)
compass-rails (1.0.3)
cucumber (1.2.1, 1.1.4 ruby, 0.10.0)
cucumber-rails (1.3.0, 1.2.1 ruby, 0.3.2)
cucumber-websteps (0.9.0 ruby)
daemons (1.1.9, 1.1.8)
data_mapper (1.2.0, 0.9.11)
data_objects (0.10.9, 0.9.12)
database_cleaner (0.7.0 ruby)
debugger (1.2.0)
debugger-linecache (1.1.2)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.1.3)
devise (2.1.2, 2.0.4)
diff-lcs (1.1.3 ruby, 1.1.2)
dm-aggregates (1.2.0, 0.9.11)
dm-cli (1.2.0, 0.9.11)
dm-constraints (1.2.0)
dm-core (1.2.0, 0.9.11)
dm-is-tree (1.2.0, 0.9.11)
dm-migrations (1.2.0, 0.9.11)
dm-observer (1.2.0, 0.9.11)
dm-serializer (1.2.2, 0.9.11)
dm-timestamps (1.2.0, 0.9.11)
dm-transactions (1.2.0)
dm-types (1.2.2, 0.9.11)
dm-validations (1.2.0, 0.9.11)
do_mysql (0.10.9)
dragonfly (0.9.12)
dropbox-sdk (1.5.1, 1.1)
eco (1.0.0)
eco-source (1.1.0.rc.1)
ejs (1.1.1, 1.0.0)
erubis (2.7.0 ruby, 2.6.6)
eventmachine (1.0.0, 1.0.0.rc.4, 0.12.10)
exception_notification (2.5.2 ruby)
excon (0.16.4, 0.16.1)
execjs (1.4.0 ruby, 1.3.0)
extlib (0.9.15)
factory_girl (4.1.0, 2.4.2 ruby, 1.3.3)
factory_girl_rails (4.1.0)
faraday (0.8.4 ruby)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
ffi (1.1.5, 1.0.11 ruby)
filters_spam (0.3)
formtastic (2.2.1 ruby, 1.2.3)
friendly_id (4.0.8, 4.0.7)
fssm (0.2.9)
gherkin (2.11.2, 2.7.3 ruby, 2.3.3)
gli (2.3.0)
globalize3 (0.2.0)
gmaps4rails (1.5.5)
guard (1.4.0)
guard-rspec (2.0.0)
haml (3.1.7)
haml-rails (0.3.5)
hashie (1.2.0)
hello-world (1.2.0)
hello_world (0.0.2)
heroku (2.32.8, 2.30.3)
heroku-api (0.3.5, 0.3.4)
hike (1.2.1 ruby)
hirb (0.7.0)
htmlentities (4.3.1)
httpauth (0.2.0, 0.1)
i18n (0.6.1 ruby, 0.6.0 ruby, 0.5.0)
jist (1.0.1)
journey (1.0.4 ruby)
jquery-rails (2.1.3, 2.1.2 ruby, 2.1.1 ruby, 2.0.2, 1.0.19)
jquery-ui-rails (2.0.2, 2.0.0)
json (1.7.5 ruby, 1.7.3, 1.6.6, 1.6.3, 1.4.6)
json_pure (1.7.5)
jwt (0.1.5)
launchy (2.1.2, 2.0.5 ruby)
less (2.2.2)
less-rails (2.2.3)
lesstile (1.1.0, 1.0.1 ruby)
libv8 (3.11.8.3 x86_64-darwin-10, 3.3.10.4 x86_64-darwin-10)
libwebsocket (0.1.5)
listen (0.5.3)
mail (2.4.4 ruby, 2.3.3, 2.2.19, 2.2.15)
market_beat (0.2.0)
method_source (0.8)
methodfinder (1.2.5)
mime-types (1.19 ruby, 1.18, 1.16)
mongo (1.7.0)
mongodb (2.1.0)
multi_json (1.3.6 ruby, 1.2.0, 1.0.4 ruby)
multipart-post (1.1.5 ruby)
netrc (0.7.7)
nokogiri (1.5.5, 1.5.0 ruby)
oauth (0.4.7, 0.4.5)
oauth2 (0.8.0)
omniauth (1.1.1)
omniauth-facebook (1.4.1)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1, 1.1.0)
open_id_authentication (1.1.0 ruby)
orm_adapter (0.4.0, 0.0.7)
paper_trail (2.6.3)
pg (0.14.0)
polyglot (0.3.3 ruby, 0.3.1)
pry (0.9.10, 0.8.3)
pry-doc (0.4.4)
pry-nav (0.2.2 ruby)
pry-rails (0.2.2, 0.2.0)
pry-remote (0.1.6 ruby)
pry-stack_explorer (0.4.7)
rack (1.4.1 ruby, 1.3.6, 1.2.5, 1.2.1)
rack-cache (1.2 ruby)
rack-flash (0.1.2)
rack-mount (0.8.3, 0.6.14, 0.6.13)
rack-openid (1.3.1 ruby, 1.2.0)
rack-protection (1.2.0 ruby)
rack-ssl (1.3.2 ruby)
rack-test (0.6.2, 0.6.1 ruby, 0.5.7)
rails (3.2.8 ruby, 3.2.6, 3.1.3, 3.0.4)
rails3-generators (0.17.6)
rails_autolink (1.0.9)
railties (3.2.8 ruby, 3.2.6, 3.1.3, 3.0.4)
rake (0.9.2.2 ruby, 0.8.7)
rb-fsevent (0.9.2)
rdiscount (1.6.8)
rdoc (3.12 ruby)
redcarpet (2.1.1)
RedCloth (4.2.9 ruby, 4.2.8)
refinerycms (2.0.8, 2.0.5)
refinerycms-authentication (2.0.8, 2.0.5)
refinerycms-blog (2.0.4)
refinerycms-core (2.0.8, 2.0.5)
refinerycms-dashboard (2.0.8, 2.0.5)
refinerycms-i18n (2.0.2, 2.0.0)
refinerycms-images (2.0.8, 2.0.5)
refinerycms-pages (2.0.8, 2.0.5)
refinerycms-resources (2.0.8, 2.0.5)
refinerycms-settings (2.0.2)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rmagick (2.13.1)
routing-filter (0.3.1)
rspec (2.11.0, 2.8.0 ruby, 2.5.0)
rspec-core (2.11.1, 2.8.0 ruby, 2.5.1)
rspec-expectations (2.11.3, 2.8.0 ruby, 2.5.0)
rspec-mocks (2.11.3, 2.8.0 ruby, 2.5.0)
rspec-rails (2.11.0, 2.8.1 ruby, 2.5.0)
ruby-openid (2.2.1, 2.1.8 ruby)
ruby_parser (2.3.1)
rubyzip (0.9.9, 0.9.5 ruby)
sass (3.2.1 ruby, 3.1.20, 3.1.15, 3.1.12 ruby)
sass-rails (3.2.5 ruby, 3.2.3 ruby, 3.1.6)
scrapi (2.0.0, 1.2.0)
selenium-webdriver (2.25.0, 2.17.0 ruby)
seo_meta (1.3.0)
sexp_processor (3.2.0)
simple_form (2.0.3, 2.0.2)
simple_oauth (0.1.9)
sinatra (1.3.3 ruby)
sinatra-static-assets (1.0.4)
slop (3.3.3)
sprockets (2.6.0, 2.1.3 ruby, 2.0.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.6 ruby, 1.3.5 ruby, 1.3.3)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
stringex (1.4.0)
strong_parameters (0.1.3)
term-ansicolor (1.0.7 ruby, 1.0.5)
therubyracer (0.10.2)
thin (1.5.0, 1.4.1 ruby)
thor (0.16.0 ruby, 0.15.4, 0.14.6)
tidy (1.1.2)
tidy_ffi (0.1.4)
tilt (1.3.3 ruby)
treetop (1.4.10 ruby, 1.4.9)
truncate_html (0.5.5)
turn (0.9.6, 0.8.2)
twitter (4.0.0, 3.7.0)
twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.1.3)
twix (0.0.1)
tzinfo (0.3.33 ruby, 0.3.24)
uglifier (1.3.0 ruby, 1.2.6, 1.2.4)
uuidtools (2.1.3)
warden (1.2.1, 1.1.1)
webrat (0.7.3 ruby)
will_paginate (3.0.3, 3.0.2 ruby, 3.0.pre2)
xml-simple (1.1.1)
xpath (0.1.4 ruby)
yahoo_sports (0.2.1, 0.2.0)
yard (0.8.2.1)
```

Answer (score 8):

To fix the problem I did

```
brew uninstall node

brew install node
```

This seems to be a common problem with people who have uninstalled MacPorts. Googling around, I've discovered that people have had to uninstall postgres or mysql as well, depending on the unique circumstances.

Comment: what does 'node' mean here?

Comment: I did it because of this line in the error message:  'Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node' Check your errors. If it says something other than 'node' try brew install 'whatevererrormessagesays'

Answer (score 4):

You should just update `yarn`:

```
brew upgrade yarn
```

and run

```
yarn install
```